# Custom mybatis mapper for 2 columns

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a requirement where in I will be getting back data from 2 columns like day and month but I want to convert it in to a Date object nd set it into my bean class.

Is this possible without adding the property to the java class?

I tried checking for custom result handler but the examples were not clear enough.Are there hooks to run some kind of custom handler before returning back from the select method?

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about in MyBatis terms is called a **Result Map** Which is used to map fields withing a type to columns withing a database table.

It can be set up in two ways.
 **XML** **Config**:

```
<resultMap id = "result" type = "Date">
   <result property = "month" column = "monthcolumn"/>
   <result property = "day" column = "daycolumn"/>
   <result property = "year" column = "yearcolumn"/>
</resultMap>

<select id = "getDate" resultMap = "result">
   SELECT * FROM yourtable.dates
</select>
```

Or if you are using **Java Annotations:**

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM yourtable.dates")
@Results(value = {
@Result(property = "day", column = "daycolumn"),
@Result(property = "month", column = "monthcolumn"),
@Result(property = "year", column = "yearcolumn")})     
public Date getDate();
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.. I do not want to add the property in my java class. My java class already has a date filed and I want to map to that field by combining the result of col1 & col 2